# error : command 'gcc' failed with exit status when installing pandas on centos6.7

Tags: python-2.7, gcc, pandas

I'm trying to install pandas on my CentOS6.7. I've tried running the following commands `pip install pandas`, `easy_install pandas` and `python setup.py install`, but I'm keeping receiving the same error message : `command 'gcc' failed with exit status`.

After googling, I found that some other packages should be installed for resolving this problem. However after installing the following packages : `python-devel`, `libxml2-devel`, `libxslt-devel`, `Cython`, `lxml`, The error is always there.

For more information, I've upgraded python version from 2.6 to 2.7.6 on CentOS.

Thanks for any help.

--UPDATE--

I append the some error message here :

`pip install pandas
Collecting pandas
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py:90: InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.
  InsecurePlatformWarning
  Using cached pandas-0.16.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->pandas)
Building wheels for collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pandas
  Complete output from command /usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-HceY7B/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpavjUtXpip-wheel-:
(too long here...)
  gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include/python2.7 -c pandas/algos.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/pandas/algos.o
    In file included from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1804,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:17,
                     from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/algos.c:242:
    /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    gcc: Internal error: Killed (program cc1)
    Please submit a full bug report.
    See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
Command "/usr/local/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-HceY7B/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-je0QNu-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-HceY7B/pandas`

Comment: sudo yum install gcc ?

Comment: In general you have the message which caused this error just before this, can you add it to the question?

Comment: @YOBA I have gcc installed. I appended the error message in my post.

Comment: the command that failed seems to have no permission to access certain files, trivial question but have you tried with >> sudo pip install pandas ?

Comment: @YOBA Yes I've tried with `sudo pip install pandas`. It did not work.

Comment: @kyan have you solved this? I had an almost same problem.

Comment: @SCaffrey have you solved it?

Comment: @User No I Didn't.